# Find last shutdown time

Tags: logs, time, shutdown

This is the command I am using:

```
last -x|grep shutdown | head -1
```

but it's giving me the duration with +2 hours:

```
shutdown system down  3.14-1-amd64     Mon Jul 21 08:43 - 22:19  (13:36)
```

the last shutdown time (08:43) is correct, but the startup time (22:19, should be 20:19) is incorrect.

Is there a better command to check how long ago the PC was shutdown? or is my DST settings or something else causing this?

PS: I am using Debian testing *(Linux rig 3.14-1-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.14.12-1 (2014-07-11) x86_64 GNU/Linux)*

Comment: Which O.S. are you using?

Comment: Are you sure that the time is given +2 hours, I have tried it and it worked.

Comment: In the reboot line that is adjacent to this shutdown line, does it also show the incorrect startup time?

Comment: `who -b` gives last system boot time `last reboot` gives also what command says. If you suspect on DST settings check current date and compare it with real values and let us know

Comment: @klerk `who -b` gives incorrect value: `semko@rig:~$ who -b
         system boot  2014-07-22 00:24
semko@rig:~$ date
Mon Jul 21 22:41:35 CEST 2014
`. so you can see that it is off by 2 hrs from `date`. `semko@rig:~$ last reboot
reboot   system boot  3.14-1-amd64     Tue Jul 22 00:24 - 22:41  (-1:-42)` is the last entry, and the -1:-42 is just absurd.

Comment: Interesting. So you're 2 hours ahead of UTC? Is your BIOS clock kept in UTC or the local time?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick I am guessing it is kept [local](http://i.imgur.com/mlCDz34.jpg). But there is no UTC/local setting on my [BIOS](http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=2539#ov).

Comment: My hunch is that the software on Linux that records system boot time is running without knowing your correct timezone and is interpreting the hardware clock's time as UTC. Do you set your timezone using a shell variable, or do you use an `/etc/timezone` and/or `/etc/localtime` file?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick Well, I am using KDE's date & time [module](http://i.imgur.com/CsQsixl.png) (set to local, at least that's what it shows). It's also set to sync with the [europe.pool.ntp.org](http://i.imgur.com/AXNCPFp.png).

Comment: Can you post the contents of /etc/timezone and /etc/sysconfig/clock and the output of `ls -l /etc/localtime` ?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick [Here](http://paste.debian.net/111104/). But I don't have a /etc/sysconfig/clock.

Comment: They look OK. I have just one suggestion: use UTC for the BIOS time. Most Linux servers do this. As root, run `hwclock --utc`, then run `date` to check and set the correct time - it will probably be 2 hours off - then reboot.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15900/discussion-between-infestor-and-mark-plotnick).

Comment: Output in UTC:
`$ TZ= last`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

According to your output:

```
shutdown system down  3.14-1-amd64     Mon Jul 21 08:43 - 22:19  (13:36)
```

You shutdown your system on July 21 at 08:43 and then after 13 hours and 36 minutes on July 21 at 22:19 you boot it up again. You can see how much time your system is up with `uptime` command. If you want to see the last time you boot up (not shutdown) use the following command:

```
 last -x | grep reboot
```

For example my output is:

```
reboot   system boot  4.4.0-31-generic Mon Aug  1 12:59   still running
reboot   system boot  4.4.0-31-generic Mon Aug  1 01:28 - 08:54  (07:25)
```

Now it's easy to understand that I booted up my system on August 1 at 12:59 and it's still running. And I was working with my computer for 7 hours and 25 minutes from 01:28 to 08:54 on August 1.
Hope it will be useful! :-)

Answer (score 8):

I'm using OS Fedora and command:
`last -1x shutdown
shutdown system down  3.15.3-200.fc20. Fri Jul 11 12:31 - 12:31  (00:00)
wtmp begins Sat Dec 28 12:28:14 2013`

Answer (score 3):

If you are using systemd (and have journald logs permanently stored on disk), you could use `journalctl -b-1` and then go to the end of the logs

Answer (score 1):

Another good alternative is the use of the command `tuptime`.

The following example lists information on the last two operating system runs, among others shutdown time:

```
$ tuptime  -l -S-2
Startup:  1379  at  13:51:57 06/01/18
Uptime:   10 minutes and 54 seconds
Shutdown: OK  at  14:02:51 06/01/18
Downtime: 19 hours, 31 minutes and 53 seconds

Startup:  1380  at  09:34:44 07/01/18
Uptime:   22 minutes and 59 seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

You could call `uptime` and do the math:

```
# uptime
 11:56:42 up 64 days, 13:27,  4 users,  load average: 0,00, 0,03, 0,11
```

Comment: This doesn't help to known about a shutdown or restart, because you are already up at command time. This kind of question is more about "to know when the computer has went off", which is my case too. All we know about logs, but there are always a nicer way to do things, like `last`.

Answer (score 0):

As friends said `who`,`last` and `uptime` will help you but you can check `/var/log/messages`. If your system was idle you would find `Mark` in logs and find last `Mark` will help you to find when system down and when system start up syslog write the kernel and services log on `/var/log/messages`. You can find out when services getting start.